# Is there a way to set individual Android activities to be transparent?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-transitions

I have a base background image for the entire android app that I am developing. But during custom animation transitions, the background image slides with the activity. Is there a way to keep the background stationary so that only the individual elements within the activity slide with the transitions? Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible for you to convert your activities into fragments? if so then you can have a MainActivity with the background on a RelativeLayout. You can use animations to swap out fragments which will get you the effect you are looking for.

Comment: @MitchDart,  I agree